# Alterar Menu horizontal para vertical com dropdown

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-3

Boa tarde, tenho este menu em bootstrap do w3school. O menu é horizontal e tem o dropdown vertical.
Pretendia colocar o menu em vertical, ou seja, por baixo do Home ter o Page1, depois o Page 2 por baixo do Page1. Pretendia também colocar o dropdown na horizontal em vez de estar na vertical, ou seja, ao clicar em page1 em vez de abrir o dropdown por baixo, abrir ao lado de page1.
Até 768px ele mostra na vertical, mas a partir disso mostra na horizontal e não estou a conseguir alterar as propriedades de modo a colocar o menu na vertical. 
Alguém me consegue ajudar? 
Tem aí o código.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

</head>
<body>

<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
    </div>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Page 1 <span class="caret"></span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="#">Page 1-1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Page 1-2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Page 1-3</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
  
<div class="container">
  <h3>Navbar With Dropdown</h3>
  <p>This example adds a dropdown menu for the "Page 1" button in the navigation bar.</p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Cara me parece que é um projeto que vc está começando agora, mas pq usar Bootstrap 3?? O Bootstrap 4 foi lançado em 2017, e o Bootstrap 5 está em vias de ser lançado, não tem justificativa começar algo em BS3 hoje em dia... Te digo isso tb pq aqui tem metade da sua resposta, mas fiz em BS4 https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/350199/navbar-vertical e esquece BS3 para o seu bem :D

Comment: Pois, realmente sou novo no Bootstrap. Estou na faculdade e ia agora começar a aprender bootstrap e quis me antecipar um pouco e começar a ver como funciona, o que é e tentar alguns projetos. Irei ver o seu projeto para perceber como devo fazer as coisas. Muito obrigado